# Prove that $n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k$ converges in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of uncorrelated random variables with common mean $\mu$, such that $\sup_n$Var$(X_n)<\infty$. If $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$, show that
$n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k$ converges in probability as $n\to\infty$ and identify the limit.

I know that using Weak Laws of Large Numbers, it is easily proven that $\frac{S_n}{n}\to\mu$ in $L^2$, and thus converges to $\mu$ in probability as well. But I'm having trouble using this result to prove that $n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k$ converges in probability. I think it would help to know the limit (at least intuitively) to prove this, but I'm a bit stuck on this problem.

**My attempt:**
First note that $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n^2}\leq\frac{nS_n}{n^2}=\frac{S_n}{n}$$
Then since we know $E(\lvert \frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\rvert^2)\to 0$, $E(\lvert\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n^2}-\mu \rvert^2)\leq E(\lvert \frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\rvert^2)$ by monotonicity (since expectations are integrals, and monotonicity holds for integals), and thus $E(\lvert\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n^2}-\mu \rvert^2)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Now using Markov's inequality, I can conclude that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nS_k}{n^2}\to\mu$ in probability.

I kind of get the feeling that my answer may be incorrect. I would love for someone to provide some hints/point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Why is $\sum_{k=1}^nS_k\leq nS_n$?

Comment: @carmichael561 that's where I thought my answer could be wrong. That would be only true if the ${X_n}$ are all positive... But that may not be true... I could use some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from Chebyshev's inequality that if $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables with finite second moments such that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]\to\mu$ and $\mathrm{var}(Y_n)\to0$, then $Y_n\to\mu$ in probability.

Now note that we can write
$$ \sum_{k=1}^nS_k=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)X_k$$
Therefore 
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k\Big]=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\mu\to \frac{\mu}{2}$$
as $n\to\infty$, and since the $X_k$ are uncorrelated with $\sup_k\mathrm{var}(X_k)<\infty$,
$$ \mathrm{var}\Big(n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k\Big)=n^{-4}\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)^2\mathrm{var}(X_k)\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$, so the result follows by setting $Y_n=n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k$.

Comment: Var$(Y_n$ does not need to go to $0$, just need to be finite, doesn't it?

Comment: For the approach I had in mind you do really want $\mathrm{var}(Y_n)\to 0$, and fortunately that is the case here.

Comment: $Y_n$ will converge to $\mu/2$ in probability right?

Comment: Yes, good point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} S_k$. Then $\frac {T_n} {n^{2}}=\frac {1(S_1-1\mu)/1+\cdots+(n(S_n-n\mu)/n} {n^{2}}+\mu \frac {n(n+1)} {2n^{2}}$. By triangle inequality for $L^{2}$ norm it is easy to see that the first term tends to $0$ in  $L^{2}$ norm. Hence the limit (in  $L^{2}$ norm, hence also in probability) is $\mu /2$.